# Can we say "I'll be there one hour later" instead of "I'll be there in an hour"?

Tags: time, future-time

I understan "I'll be there in an hour." is a correct sentence, but if I make the sentence to "I'll be there one hour later." is that correct? and same meaning?
if not, why is it incorrect?
i'm wondering if i can use "five minutes later or one hour later" instead of in five minutes or in an hour" when i make future sentences.
like I'll be back in an hour, I'll come back in five minutes.

Comment: I google-checked "there an hour later", and got only 420 results. For "be there an hour later" or "be there one hour later", only a couple dozen results. This expression seems untypical for some reason.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you want to use the word "later". For me, "later" must be used in reference to some other mentioned time.

Comment: @CopperKettle - I believe the word "untypical" is, er, atypical... [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=untypical%2Catypical&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuntypical%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Catypical%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 24):

"I'll be there in an hour" denotes arrival in one hour from the time the words are said. "**An** hour" is also generally used to be a bit vague, whereas "I'll be there in **one** hour" is generally used to be more specific. Either way, the clock starts from the time it's stated.

"I'll be there one hour later" implies that it will be later *than* something, i.e. one hour later than already agreed. If you'd agreed to meet at 15:00, this means you'll be arriving at 16:00 instead. You could say "I'll be an hour late" to convey a similar meaning.

Comment: "Tiffany will arrive at the agreed location at two o'clock. I'll be there one hour later."

Comment: Similar case, where it's later *than* a specified time.

Comment: Or relative to some other time in context like say: "I can't leave with until I get this task done. I'll be there an hour later."